# ASP.NET: Adding xml node to first position of file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I´d like to have news feed on my web, so I create admin page and simple form to add news node to xml file. But it add node to last position, I need it on first position.

My code (in C#):

```
        XmlDocument xmlfile = new XmlDocument();
        xmlfile.Load(Server.MapPath("/News.xml"));

        XmlElement News = xmlfile.CreateElement("news");
        XmlElement Title = xmlfile.CreateElement("title");
        XmlElement Content = xmlfile.CreateElement("content");
        XmlText TitleText = xmlfile.CreateTextNode(TextBox_title.Text);
        XmlText ContentText = xmlfile.CreateTextNode(TextBox_content.Text);

        Title.AppendChild(TitleText);
        Content.AppendChild(ContentText);
        News.AppendChild(Title);
        News.AppendChild(Content);
        XmlNode news = xmlfile.GetElementsByTagName("news")[0];

        //xmlfile.DocumentElement.AppendChild(News);

        xmlfile.Save(Server.MapPath("/News.xml"));
```

My xml file:

```
<theNews>
  <news>
    <title>
      Example title
    </title>
    <content>
      Example content.
    </content>
  </news>
</theNews>
```

Code what reading xml:

```
`<asp:ListView ID="NewsList" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <h2><%# XPath("title") %></h2>
            <p>
                <%# XPath("content") %>
                <hr />
            </p>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource" runat="server" DataFile="~/News.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource>`
```

Comment: And how do you parse this XML ? Why don't you simply append at the end of the file, then render your file in reverse order when parsing it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `PrependChild` instead of `AppendChild`:

```
xmlfile.DocumentElement.PrependChild(News);
```